# PHP - fetch json data

Tags: php

I have problem with this script...

My script has return this:

```
{
"categories": {
    "cid": "1",
    "name": "Pierwsza pomoc"
}
}{
"categories": {
    "cid": "2",
    "name": "Poradniki"
}
}{
"categories": {
    "cid": "3",
    "name": "Klany"
}
}{
"categories": {
    "cid": "4",
    "name": "Eventy, imprezy"
}
}{
"categories": {
    "cid": "5",
    "name": "Rozm\u00f3wki"
}
}{
"categories": {
    "cid": "6",
    "name": "Quest, solucje"
}
}{
"categories": {
    "cid": "7",
    "name": "Off topic"
}
}
```

But i want to this

```
[
    'categories': {
          'cid': 1,
          'name': 'test',
          'cid': 2,
          'name': 'asdsad',
          'cid': 3,
          'name': 'asdasd'
    }
]
```

Code used to create the data is

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0){ 
    foreach($query as $row){ 
        $Forum->writeJSON(array('categories' => array( 'cid' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name'] ))); 
    } 
}



class Forum { 
    public function writeJSON($array){ 
        echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
    } 
} 

$Forum = new Forum;
```

Comment: Show us the script that generates this data structure

Comment: The dictionary in your desired output has the same keys ('cid' and 'name') multiple times.

Comment: if($query->rowCount() > 0){

                                                 foreach($query as $row){
                                                     $Forum->writeJSON(array('categories' => array(
                                                                      'cid' => $row['id'],
                                                                      'name' => $row['name']
                                                      )));
                                                 }
                                          }

Comment: @DavidCullen Errr yes, thats why he wants the data to be held in an array of objects

Comment: Now you had better show us what `$Forum->writeJSON` does as thats not vanilla PHP.

Comment: class Forum {
  public function writeJSON($array){
   echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  }
}

$Forum = new Forum;

Comment: I want like this JSON: http://morigan.pl/WebModuleWebsite?task=get_topics&section=3&uid=-1&shsh=-1

Comment: @RiggsFolly: php > var blah = [ 'categories': { 'cid': 1, 'name': 'test', 'cid': 2, 'name': 'asdad', 'cid': 3, 'name': 'asdasd' } ];

Parse error: parse error in php shell code on line 1

Comment: You do realise that data inside `{}` denotes an OBJECT and not an array dont you! Arrays are denoted by `[]` And therefore your _But i want to this format_ is not a valid object, or array come to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this structure is not possible. You cannot store two or more elements with exactly same key in same object. However maybe you simply want this output:

```
[ 'categories' : { 1: {category_id:1, name:'test'}, 2: {category_id:2, name:'test'} } ]
```

It is simple, for example, you can use something like this to form that array:

```
<?php
//fetch data into categories variable
$output = array();
$output['categories'] = array();
foreach ($category as $category){
  $output['categories'][] = array('category_id' => $category['id'], 'name' => $category['name']);
}
$output = json_encode($output);
?>
```

PS: Please use the correct variable names in your code, this is just an example using fictitious variable names

Comment: Yea this output i want: So what should i do to going this? I want this 
[
   'categories': {
      1: {
           category_id: 1,
           name: 'blablabla'
      },
      2: {
         category_id: 2,
         name: 'blablanla'
      },
      3: {
        category_id: 3,
        name: 'blablabla'
      }
   }
]
sorry my english i bad :C

Comment: It is alright, I understand it. Do you want me to write php workaround?

Comment: please write script for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `foreach` loop code

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0){ 
 foreach($query as $row){
    $cat_array[$row['id']] = array('cid'=>$row['id'],'name'=>$row['name']);
 }
  $json_array[] = array('categories'=>$cat_array);
  $Forum->writeJSON($json_array);
}
```